# Differences between Until vs Up to vs As on

Tags: prepositions, time-reference

I have two queries regarding how to use until/up to. I have searched a lot, but I couldn't find a satisfactory answer.

1. Suppose, someone submits a report, which was updated up to 31st October 2019. However, the report does not mention the date. Which of the following interrogative structure would be appropriate  for asking about that date? The answer to the question is 31st Oct 2019.

   ```
   a) When was the report last updated?
   b) How latest/recent is the information in the report?
   c) What date has the report been updated until/up to?
   d) Until/up to what time has the report been updated?
   ```
2. Can 'until' be used to describe an activity that has already happened? As far as I know, until is used to describe an state/situation/activity that continued up to a certain point in time. For example,

   ```
   a) We have constructed 100 houses as on 31st October.
   b) We have constructed 100 houses till/until 31st October.
   ```

   Here, the construction has already happened. I think use of 'until' is inappropriate here.

   Also, how would one ask that in question? Which of these formations are correct?

   ```
   how many houses had been/were constructed until/up to/as on 31st October?
   ```

Comment: Note: 'up to' is a phrase of two words.

Comment: Thanks. I am aware of it, but while typing I made the mistake.

Comment: 1a and 2a work.